# MSAL4J Integrated windows Authentication - Null Reference exception inside the MSAL4J code

Tags: java, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to do a POC for a simple Java Console application accessing Graph API using the demo code AS IS from the link here
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-desktop/tree/master/Integrated-Windows-Auth-Flow

The code breaks with the below exception.  Java seems to have issues with Integrated Auth, and the Null Reference exception is not giving any hints as to what could be wrong. Any help or suggestions is much appreciated.

*Note: My Java Version is "1.8.0_261" and I know the app registration steps are working as I tested it from .NET client. I was also able to get the username/password flow working using MSAL for Java but Integrated Auth is having this issue*

```
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] ERROR com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.PublicClientApplication - [Correlation ID: ec8337fa-d27e-4f39-83f5-a1f99984d469] Execution of class  com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier failed.
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.WSTrustResponse.parse(WSTrustResponse.java:74)
        at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.WSTrustRequest.execute(WSTrustRequest.java:48)
        at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.WSTrustRequest.execute(WSTrustRequest.java:89)
        at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier.getAuthorizationGrantIntegrated(AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier.java:126)
        at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier.execute(AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier.java:40)
        at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.get(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:59)
        at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.get(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:17)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source)
```

Update: From fiddler trace, I was able to see my .NET application that works is using NTLM and the documentation for the demo says MSAL4J needs Kerberos. I am assuming Kerberos is not turned on in my environment.

Comment: Not actually use Azsure before, but I know that the windows Integrated Auth needs to run in a windows domain. Did you run this program in a trusted computer of windows domain?

Comment: Yes Houcheng, it am running on a windows machine that is domain joined. It is using NTLM authentication. I am going try to run this in an environment running Kerberos and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

MSAL Java expects that a Kerberos ticket is available. You can generate one when you test by running [Kinit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/kinit.html), which is part of the JDK.

Note that before running kinit the machine has to be domain joined and that the user should be a principal in the Key Distribution Center.